# Как перезагрузить устройство без root, используя kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

Например у меня есть функция, которая срабатывает при нажатии на кнопку.

```
 fun onClickRestartBtn(view: View) {

 }
```

Что мне нужно написать в нее, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку устройство перезагружалось?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32984849/restarting-a-device-programmatically

Comment: [Очень просто](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4966542). [Подпишите приложение системным ключом](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3656925)